# show a fixed number of cells in every row in a UICollectionView

Tags: iphone, ios, uicollectionview

I want to create fixed number of rows in every cell, and to note is that each section may has multiple number of rows. Say, that there are 20 cells and each row must contain 9 cells in it. So, the number of cells should be 9x3 = 27. 20 cells and remaining 7 cells should be of different colors, there should be three rows then depending on the number of cells. Same thing applied on each section Suppose having three sections then each section will have same story, depending on the number of cells in each section. If anyone has done any such thing, please guide.

```
- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
NSLog(@"vals count:%d", [arrSeats count]);
for(int i=0; i<[arrLevels count]; i++)
{
    if(section == i)
    {
        int c;
        NSString *cnt = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arrTot objectAtIndex:i]];
        c = [cnt intValue];
        return c;
    }
}
return 1;
}
```

This is the way i am providing each section different number of cells.

Comment: can you post some code. It will be helpfull

Comment: You have a value in arrTot array. You have used it correctly. What you want to do? Cant understand

Comment: @Durgaprasad ya that's right but i want to ask is that i set my UICollectionView frame as it will contain 9 cells in a row, if cells in a section is 20 it should show 27 items 20 are assigned cells remaining 7 should be generated automatically means the above method should automatically return 27, so that the row should be completely filled with cells.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am answering depending on what I understood from your question. Check if it works for you.
If you have 20 cells(array.count) and you want 9 cells in one row then number of rows will be

```
numOfRow = 20/9; //2
if(20 % 9 > 0)
    numOfRow +=1;  //2+1 = 3
numOfCell = numOfRow*9;
```

Try this if works.

Comment: k njoy codding if this code works dont forget to accept answer

Comment: need some help in above question can you?

Comment: I need to change the color of both type cells, means 20 cells have different and 7 cells have different color.

Comment: there will be a method for cell for row. In that you will get row Num. Use same calculation as above. if numOfRow == 3 then check numOfCellWithDiffColor=numOfCell-20; It will be 7. You need to give diff color there. If you dont understand put that code in question. I will check

Comment: i think logic is done can you tell how to change the image of cell at particular indexes, how to check which cell is this.

Comment: now i am doing this way  if(cell.selected){
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow_seat.png"]];  // highlight selection
    }
    else
    {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"blue_s.png"]]; // Default color
    }

Comment: if(cell.selected) working? You tried NSLog in that? If yes then cell.backgroundColorView else give cell.backgroundView with that color.

Comment: check the question posted.